# Create Pull Request Button is disabled

Tags: github, pull-request

I would like to make a pull request from my fork repo to the upstream repository.

As always I was following these steps [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork) from **the guidance from Github.**

But this time I can not make a pull request, as the button is *disabled.*

The branches can be automatically merged.

I do have changes in my forked repo and I can see commits made.
Base repo and head repo are indicated correctly.

Comment: What happens *after* you've filled in the title and description? Are there enabled options in the dropdown on that button?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. While a screenshot can sometimes be useful, this one is maybe not showing the most informative things for the problem at hand. You said the button was disabled and we're ready to take your word for it, no need for a proof. What *would* be more useful is your branches situation.

Comment: Well, title is filled in as well as the description, but still, the button is disabled. 
@jonrsharpe Do you mean the "create draft pull request" option from dropdown? If yes, it is disabled also

Comment: @RomainValeri you are right, the image is unnecessary. What about branches situation?

Comment: Are the branches to be merged from different repos? Have you double-checked authorizations for submitting pull requests here?

Comment: happened to me before and it was because i forgot to add title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Github Developer Support:

> Also, I know this might seem strange, but could you try selecting the
>   base repo/branch from the drop down list (even if this already seems
>   selected), and give this another go. It could that, for whatever
>   reason, the pull request creation flow isn't picking this up
>   implicitly.

I have also logged out and logged in again.

After that, everything was fine!

Answer (score 186):

In my case, the pull request ***Title*** field didn't auto-populate like it usually does. Once I typed in a title, the button became active.

Comment: This happened to me when making changes related to the readme

Comment: An indicator wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Was my issue as well, thanks for posting this "obvious" answer, saved me some time.

Comment: lol, it happened to me as well :)

Answer (score 12):

make sure to put something in the title, I forgot to add one here
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hello I encountered the same issue then noticed that the button is inactive because you have not given the title to the PR. Make sure you give the PR title.

Comment: Please don't repeat answers

Answer (score 1):

Populating the "comment" field did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see a button at all... and then I realised...

I wasn't logged in #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

It happened to but I realized that and immediately changed the default branch to master. The pull request button got activated thereoff.

Answer (score 0):

After realising it's just a HTML issue, I enabled the button by inspecting the element and deleting the tag  in my browser (Safari).

That should fix the issue in other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to select my branch from the list shown down on the github page labeled "There isn’t anything to compare." - weird but worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Adding a title to pr fixed the problem

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928799/2227743).